# Can anyone explain to me this syntax in JS w/ React "{posts && posts.map((post)=> ( "

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to JS and React and i'm currently working on a project using React.

The project in question is a social media app where you create posts.

I wanted to use fetch to get a list of "posts" and then use react to format them. I was able to get it to work from a post online, however I don't quite understand the syntax.

Here is the code..

```
function App() {
const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/posts')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then((posts) => {
        console.log(posts)
        setPosts(posts);
    });
}, []);
return (
    <div>
        {posts && posts.map((post)=> (
            <div class="container"> 
                <div class="row border mt-2">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {post.owner}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {post.content}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        {post.created_at}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        likes: {post.likes}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

In particular I don't really understand **posts && posts.map((post)=>** in the return statement. It confuses me that there is an AND (&&) conditional where I am returning both the "posts" array as well as a mapped version of the array? Is there something I'm missing.

Comment: Basically means, do this `posts.map(...)` if `posts` is truthy (not null, not undefined, not false). You can also use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `posts?.map(...)`

Comment: Keyword [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation) - this is a way of preventing that `posts.map()` would throw an error, if `posts` was empty or not set at this point. Consider it a "nicer" form of `if(posts) { posts.map() }`

Comment: Thank you for the replies! It's much clearer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` is the boolean AND operator. This syntax is a trick that relies on the fact that  it short circuits if the first operand is a false-y (usually `undefined`).

In a nutshell, here's what's happens:

1. The left operand (`posts`) is evaluated.
2. If it's a false-y (e.g., `undefined`), it's returned.
3. If it's a truth-y, the right operand (`posts.map(...)`) is evaluated and is returned.

It basically boils down to oneliners designed to check `posts` and if it's defined, do something with it. An arguably more-readable way of writing this would be

```js
if (!posts) {
    return posts;
}
return posts.map(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It only checks If the posts array is not empty or `undefined`, If not then return the mapped version of the posts array. Otherwise, it will return nothing.

Comment: This part is actually not correct `It only checks If the posts array is not empty`. It will call `posts.map(...)` part if the `posts` is an empty array since an empty array is defined and not falsy.